# Vec<&str>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type ()

Tags: rust

I am new to rust and cannot figure out why I can not collect after map:

```
fn spin_words(words: &str) -> String {
    let split = words.split(" ");
    let mut spinned: Vec<&str> = split
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x: &str| {
            if (x.len() >= 5) {
                x.to_string()
                    .chars()
                    .rev()
                    .collect::<String>()
                    .push_str(" ")
            } else {
                x.to_string().push_str(" ")
            }
        })
        .collect();

    //just returning empty string for the compiler
    "".to_string()
}
```

Comment: [`.push_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str) returns `()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make the following adjustments:

1. Collect into `Vec<String>`, because you construct `String` objects anyway, so you'll have to own them in the vector
2. Instead of instantiating a `String` and expanding it with data using `.push_str()`, you can instead chain the `.chars()` iterator with some other iterator and then collect into a `String`. Note that `.push_str()` is also a valid way of doing it, however it would be more verbose, as `String::push_str()` doesn't return anything, so you'd have to create some intermediate variables to hold your string.

```
fn spin_words(words: &str) -> String {
    let split = words.split(" ");
    let mut spinned: Vec<String> = split
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x: &str| {
            if (x.len() >= 5) {
                x.chars()
                 .rev()
                 .chain(" ".chars())
                 .collect::<String>()
            } else {
                x.chars().chain(" ".chars()).collect::<String>()
            }
        })
        .collect();

    //just returning empty string for the compiler
    "".to_string()
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response that makes sense. I did not realize push_str returned ()